# R randomly allocate different values from vector to dataframe column based on condition

Tags: r

I've got a dataset called `df` of answers to a question `Q1`

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Q1 = c(1,1,3,4,2))
```

I also have a vector where each element is a word

```
words = c("good","bad","better","improved","fascinating","improvise")
```

**My Objective**

- **IF** **Q1 = 1 or Q1 = 2**, then *randomly assign* a value from vector `words` to a newly created column called `followup`

**My Attempt**

```
#If answer to Q1 is 1 or 2, then randomly allocate a word to newly created column "followup"
#Else leave blank
df$followup=ifelse(df$Q1==1 | df$Q1==2,sample(words,1),"")
```

However doing this leads to repetition of the **same** randomly selected word for each row that contains a 1 or 2.

```
  ID Q1    followup
1  1  1 fascinating
2  2  1 fascinating
3  3  3            
4  4  4            
5  5  5
```

I'd like every word to be randomized and **different**.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that we may use

```
df$followup[df$Q1 %in% 1:2] <- sample(words, sum(df$Q1 %in% 1:2))
df
#   ID Q1  followup
# 1  1  1    better
# 2  2  1 improvise
# 3  3  3      <NA>
# 4  4  4      <NA>
# 5  5  2       bad
```

Since we are generating those values in a single call, `replace = FALSE` (the default value) in `sample` gives the desired result of all the values being different.